# Adding sparkline within a table in power bi

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to add sparkline in table in power bi desktop?I tried with google searching but i didn't understand the procedure.Please,anyone know the answer let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually take advantage of dynamic SVG data URIs, which can be created in DAX.

[image: Categorized as an Image URL]
[image: Actual underlying data]

Example usage of both sparklines and circles with sizes are here:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/SVG-Sparklines-Line/td-p/486271
https://dataveld.com/2018/07/16/use-svg-images-in-power-bi-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no native or custom visuals (table visuals to be specific) supports this functionality.

However, there are many custom visuals for sparkline visuals. (Note that its sparkline standalone, not with any form of a table).

Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kctIe5fw5Q8)